# Calculation with multiple conditions in R DataFrame

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following dataset about an investment returns:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1620604800, 1620604800, 1620604800, 
1620604800, 1620604800, 1627257600, 1627257600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Client = c(56203, 56203, 56203, 56203, 
56203, 56203, 56203), FundName = c("SAFRA KEPLER EQUITY HEDGE FI MULTIMERCADO", 
"SAFRA KEPLER FI MULTIMERCADO", "SAFRA S&P SPECIAL FIC MULTIMERCADO", 
"SAFRA AÇÕES LIVRE FIC AÇÕES", "SAFRA CONSUMO AMERICANO FIC AÇÕES BDR NÍVEL I", 
"SAFRA S&P SPECIAL FIC MULTIMERCADO", "SAFRA CONSUMO AMERICANO FIC AÇÕES BDR NÍVEL I"
), Nature = c("Aplicação", "Aplicação", "Aplicação", "Aplicação", 
"Aplicação", "Resgate", "Resgate"), Quantity = c(145.927569, 
62.684383, 16.964545, 57.852278, 14.900635, 0, 0), Value = c(21240, 
12120, 8760, 9120, 8760, -9157.45, -1125), Saldo = c(21240, 12120, 
8760, 9120, 8760, 55.60576570794, 9198.89221970512), FundCode = c(25079578000106, 
21144577000147, 19107923000175, 32666326000149, 19436818000180, 
19107923000175, 19436818000180), NAVInitialDate = c(145.551660000114, 
193.349593000021, 521.980031999759, 157.489282999886, 639.441026999615, 
543.077092000283, 692.849144999869), NAVYesterday = c(147.526190999895, 
196.017907999922, 531.332205999643, 166.330892999889, 675.641246000305, 
531.332205999643, 675.641246000305)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

df$NAVInitialDate = df$Value / df$Quantity
```

The 'NAVInitialDate' column is result of "Value/Quantity" for each row.
What I want to say to R is: "if in a Row we have Quantity = 0, then 'NAVInitialDate' = ABS(Value) divided by the SUM of Quantity for all rows that have the same FundName as the Fundname in the row where the Quantity is equal to 0"

The result should be, for Row 6 > NavInitialDate = 539,793 ;
for Row 7 > NavInitialDate = 75,50

How can I do this? I guess it needs 3 conditions maybe

Comment: Try `ifelse` to apply conditions.

Comment: @coffeinjunky I've tried "df$NAVMC <- ifelse(df$Quantity==0,df$NAVMC == aggregate(df$Quantity ~ df$FundName,data=df,sum),df$NAVMC)" but it results in 0 for the Rows that I want

Comment: See my attempt below, which uses the `ifelse` condition in the call to `mutate`. Here, the column `mycol` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- df %>% group_by(FundName) %>% 
  mutate(sum_Quantity = sum(Quantity), 
         mycol = ifelse(Quantity==0, abs(Value)/sum_Quantity, Value/Quantity))
```

Here you group by FundName and apply a simple `mutate` command.

To sense-check, let's have a look at the rows/columns that are of interest:

```
df %>% filter(Quantity==0) %>% select(FundName, Quantity, NAVInitialDate, mycol)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   FundName [2]
  FundName                                      Quantity NAVInitialDate mycol
  <chr>                                            <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 SAFRA S&P SPECIAL FIC MULTIMERCADO                   0           -Inf 540. 
2 SAFRA CONSUMO AMERICANO FIC AÇÕES BDR NÍVEL I        0           -Inf  75.5
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use dplyr, `group_by` FundName, and `mutate` NAVInitialDate in all `case_when` Quantity `==` 0 within the group.

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%group_by(FundName)%>%
        mutate(NAVInitialDate=case_when(Quantity==0 ~ abs(Value)/sum(Quantity, na.rm=TRUE)))

# A tibble: 7 x 10
# Groups:   FundName [5]
  Date                Client FundName       Nature Quantity  Value  Saldo FundCode NAVInitialDate
  <dttm>               <dbl> <chr>          <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>
1 2021-05-10 00:00:00  56203 SAFRA KEPLER … Aplic…    146.  21240  2.12e4  2.51e13           NA  
2 2021-05-10 00:00:00  56203 SAFRA KEPLER … Aplic…     62.7 12120  1.21e4  2.11e13           NA  
3 2021-05-10 00:00:00  56203 SAFRA S&P SPE… Aplic…     17.0  8760  8.76e3  1.91e13           NA  
4 2021-05-10 00:00:00  56203 SAFRA AÇÕES L… Aplic…     57.9  9120  9.12e3  3.27e13           NA  
5 2021-05-10 00:00:00  56203 SAFRA CONSUMO… Aplic…     14.9  8760  8.76e3  1.94e13           NA  
6 2021-07-26 00:00:00  56203 SAFRA S&P SPE… Resga…      0   -9157. 5.56e1  1.91e13          540. 
7 2021-07-26 00:00:00  56203 SAFRA CONSUMO… Resga…      0   -1125  9.20e3  1.94e13           75.5
# … with 1 more variable: NAVYesterday <dbl>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sum_0 <- sum(df[df$FundName%in%(df[df$Quantity==0,]$FundName),]$Quantity)
df$NAVInitialDate <- ifelse(df$Quantity == 0, abs(df$Value)/sum_0, df$Value / df$Quantity)
```